# Python debugging when using relative import

Tags: python, import

I'm debugging a python file and it prompts me `attempted relative import with no known parent package`.
How to solve it? Thanks!!

[image]

Comment: I am not very sure based on info you have provided. but try if this solves your problem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3

Answer (score 0):

You have to write like

```
from kitti_ultis import some_function
```

Because you are import some function from the file. First you have to write file name and then you import what ever you want in that file like function, variable, class.